# iOS tableview appearing empty in UiBuilder

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm using a long tableview.  All of the cells are visible when I run the simulation but in the UIBuilder, only the top visible cells are showing.  When I scroll further down through the table in UIBuilder, the cells are blank.  This has only been an issue since I updated Xcode.  Has anyone run into this issue before?  I'm currently using Xcode version 7.1.1

Answer (score 1):

This is a recent bug in interface builder. As a work around, change the size of the view controller in simulated metrics from inferred to freeform and increase the height until a cells render their content.